# CSS: How to set up gradient background cross browser (only missing IE8 and IE9)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, background-color, linear-gradients

I have created my own navbar and would like to set up a simple gradient background color for it.

So far I have the following which works fine for me in newer browsers but I am **not sure what I have to add here to cover IE8 and IE9** as well (I am not interested in older versions).

Also, I came across `filter: progid`... when searching for this. 
**Can someone tell me if this needs to be added here** as well to cover common browsers **or if I need to add or change anything else** for that ?
I would like to support newer versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari + IE (incl. IE8 and IE9).

**My CSS:**

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #02b0fd 0%, #028dca 100%); /* Firefox */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #02b0fd 0%, #028dca 100%); /* IE10 */  
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #02b0fd 0%, #028dca 100%); /* Opera */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #02b0fd), color-stop(1, #028dca)); /* Webkit (Safari) */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #02b0fd 0%, #028dca 100%); /* Webkit (Chrome) */
background: linear-gradient(top, #02b0fd 0%, #028dca 100%);
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0002b0fd', endColorstr='#028dca',GradientType=0 );

will give you IE6-9.

Using: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that ! Is the rest ok that I have and is the HEX code really 8 digits there ?

Comment: Going through it quickly it looks like it should work (I'm pretty sure you need background: in front of the rest of them though). Yes that hex code takes into account the opacity. If you do end up having other problems, I suggest using that colorzilla resource. It's insanely helpful!

Comment: Thanks again - big help ! Will definitely try the ColorZilla.

Comment: Just a final note: After implementing this it looks like it requires "background: " in front of all the old browser supports so I added that in my post.